# This plugin throws error on the events page only

Tags: plugins

On my clients website

http://pacificwomen.org/events/

we are getting the error on the Console and the loader is spinning but doesn't load the page. I' am already attempted many times but still it doesn't work at all. This error mostly happens when jQuery is not loading on page. But I' am already loading jQuery, Well only in Events page this is happening but the rest its working fine. My client is really angry on me regarding this issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined share-options.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5:46
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not loading jQuery at all, and actually it's commented out. So, none of your (All In One Event Calendar's) subsequent jQuery is firing.

Take a look at [WP Tuts' article on how to enqueue scripts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/).

This methodology prevents competing versions of jQuery and possible, in this case, missing scripts.

Comment: there is actually a version of jQuery there, in the file named `jquery_lib.js`.

Comment: Yes Milo, You are right. This plugin "All In One Calendar" includes jQuery. I am contacting the support of this plugin for 3 months now but they not replying at all. Is there a way I can remove this.

Comment: @NavneilNaicker It takes some time, but it loads for me. No errors in the console at all. Btw: Are you using the free version? If so, please link to the wp dot org support forum entry with an [edit] to your question. Also link there to the topic here.

Answer (score -1):

I think Jquery.js is not loading so try put in on top of your plugins so that it gets loaded first and after that load your js files

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to resolve this issue. Problem was that "Super Cache" plugin was broken.